# bayesian network library for iphone?

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, c, bayesian-networks

i m looking for a bayesian network library that work on the iphone.
any tip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it, but there's one on Github called BayesianKit:  https://github.com/lok/BayesianKit

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Open CV? It's a cross platform library by Intel, if you want to use it for image processing, it's the best available. It completely depends on what you want to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMILE library, developed by Decision Systems Laboratory, University of Pittsburgh. It's free of charge, but not open source. Registration is required to download binaries at 
http://genie.sis.pitt.edu/